# KonamiCode Error?

Tags: apache-flex

I tried to copy & paste this .. [konami code in flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546356/konami-code-in-flex)
and it doesn't work..
but i don't know why !

Here is my Project : 
http://www.rebourne.de/konami/Konami.html

> The Erromessage in Flexbuilder is :
>   Could not resolve
>    to a
>   component implementation.

Comment: Which one did you copy and paste, the top one or bottom one? And Flex 3 or 4?

Comment: @ryanstewart : The Top one.. and i use Flex 3 ---
just look at my Code.. ;) - view source is activated

Answer (score 0):

Just tested your code, works for me (FB4). Why not simply put the code into an ActionScript class an instanciate/include it in you main app?

Comment: @Thomas .. 1. There is a line commented out.
           2. I had FB3 with Flex 3.2 , so i will try it with the newer version :)